# How I hide "Taxes" from checkout page Bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

How I can hide "Taxes" from checkout page because I have already prices including tax.

I've tried to add this code in optimized-checkout.scss but it doesen't work.

```
.cart-taxes {
    display: none;
 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The cart taxes is not a class on the checkout page, it's actually an attribute. Try replacing the above code with the following one and it should work:

```
div[data-test="cart-taxes"] {
    display: none;
}
```